# Does the UFER Ground require to be visible?

Tags: electrical, drywall, grounding, foundation

Is there something on the NEC code that states the UFER ground needs to be permanently visible? I had my rough in electrical inspection the other day. He stated that per NEC 250.64(E) (1), I have to put an access panel in the drywall so that he is able to visibly see the UFER. I would rather not have an extra hole in my finished ceiling if not needed.  Nothing I find is saying this is needed.

Comment: What edition of the NEC is your inspector referring to?  250.64(E)(1) in the 2017 NEC talks about GEC-in-raceway stuff that probably does *not* apply to your situation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wrong citation, right answer

Your inspector is right, even though their NEC citation isn't.  They're after NEC 250.68(A):

> **(A) Accessibility.** All mechanical elements used to terminate a
>   grounding electrode conductor or bonding jumper to a
>   grounding electrode shall be accessible.
>
> *Exception No. 1: An encased or buried connection to a concrete-encased,
>   driven, or buried grounding electrode shall not be required to be accessible.*
>
> *Exception No. 2: Exothermic or irreversible compression connections
>   used at terminations, together with the mechanical means used to attach such terminations to fireproofed structural metal whether or not
>   the mechanical means is reversible, shall not be required to be accessible.*

So, you'll need to provide that access hatch for the "stub-up" connection from the rebar to the grounding electrode conductor, or provide some other way to access it.  If the connection is irreversable, using exothermic welding or a listed compression connector, instead of being a mechanical clamp, though, then you can cover it over -- this might be worth discussing with your electrician.

Comment: I use cad weld so it can be closed but not many electricians do this any more if the clamp can be accessed from a different location you could use that instead of a cover plate.